# How to simplify [TypeFilter(typeof(...] to [ExampleAttribute(param1, param2)]

Tags: c#, .net-core, filter

For the filter
`[TypeFilter(typeof(ExampleAttribute), Arguments = new object[] { "param1", "param2" })]`

I am looking for a way to simplify to be [ExampleAttribute(param1, param2)].
How to simplify the filter to `[ExampleAttribute(param1, param2)]`?
I received error **CS1503: cannot convert from string to FilterWrapper.**
Thanks

```
    public class ExampleAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly FilterWrapper _filter;
        private string _param1 = null;
        private string _param2 = null;

        public ExampleAttribute(
            FilterWrapper filter, string param1 = "", string param2 = "")
        {
            _filter = filter;
            _param1 = param1;
            _param2 = param2;
        }
   }
```

Comment: I don't get it, if you don't want the filter then remove it from the constructor.

Comment: can you explain more? I want this filter, but i think it is lengthy to use [TypeFilter(typeof(ExampleAttribute), Arguments = new object[] { "param1", "param2" })] , i am looking for a way to simplify to be [ExampleAttribute(param1, param2)]

Comment: Yes you said that, so again if you don't want the filter just remove it from the constructor.

Comment: I need _filter in the logics, it is an interface and created by dependency injection.

Comment: Okay well you can't both want that parameter but not want to provide it to the constructor. Also interfaces start with an `I`, not an `F`. I recommend scratching that thing and sitting down to figure out exactly what you want to do because right now you're all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the classical problem of wanting to inject a dependency into your filter?

You can use an `IFilterFactory` helper for it.

```csharp
    public class ExampleAttribute : Attribute, IFilterFactory
    {
        public bool IsReusable => false;

        public string Param1 { get; set; }
        public string Param2 { get; set; }

        public IFilterMetadata CreateInstance(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var instance = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ExampleAttributeImpl)) as ExampleAttributeImpl;
            instance.Param1 = Param1;
            instance.Param1 = Param2;
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public class ExampleAttributeImpl : IActionFilter
    {
        private readonly FilterWrapper _filter;
        public string Param1 = null;
        public string Param2 = null;

        public ExampleAttributeLogic(
            FilterWrapper filter)
        {
            _filter = filter;
        }
    }

    // And then you apply it like this:
    [Example(Param1 = "", Param2 = "")]
```

So, basically this resolves the actual filter instance from the container, along with all their dependencies.

In this implementation `Param1` and `Param2` are optional. If you want to make them required, add them to the constructor of the `IFilterFactory` implementation.

---

[More about IFilterFactory in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#ifilterfactory-implemented-on-an-attribute)

> Filters that implement IFilterFactory are useful for filters that:
>
> - Don't require passing parameters.
> - **Have constructor dependencies that need to be filled by DI.**

But as you've seen above, you can pass parameters too. :)

---

Although I have to add that I haven't been using filters that heavily these days, because I moved to using MediatR pipeline behaviors. If someone reading this knows a better way to handle these things in newer versions, let me know in the comments.